# Determine a set H of all vectors (x, y, z) ϵ R³ that are L.C. of vectors U, V and W

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let me put the enunciation first:

Let be the vectors $(U, V, W) \in \mathbb{R}^3: U = (1, 1, 5), V = (2, 1, 4), W = (-3,-1,-7)$, then determine the set $H$ of all vectors $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ that are linear combinations of the vectors $U, V$ and $W$.

I already unrolled up half of the process, but I'm stuck where I got some values for scalars $(\gamma, \beta, \alpha)$, such $\gamma = -(7x + y + z)/2, \beta = (5x + z)/2, \alpha = -2\beta + 3\gamma + x$. Sorry about this, but I don't know what to do with them.

Well, I don't know where I am failing or what I'm doing wrong, maybe I already finished and found the answers, but I'm not sure. I just can't see if I'm right or not. Don't judge me, I just lose some days of school, but I'm really interesting in hear, in fact read from you buddies what you can understand from this question. Could you help me on this? I'll be really grateful. Thanks in advance!

(If apparently looks like I'm missing something with my question, please let me know!) Thanks!

Comment: What is  L.C. ? ${}$

Comment: @DanielRust, L.C extends as 'Linear Combination' of those vectors.

Comment: f your calculations above are correct, you have almost proved that every element of $\mathbb R^3$ is in $H$. Then : $H=\mathbb R^3$. Almost because you need to show that convesly, the values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The determinant of the matrix $[U,V,W]$ is not equal to $0$ and so the matrix is non-singular. What does this tell you about the span of the vectors $\{U,V,W\}$?

Comment: in fact $\det(A)=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen "sifting"? This will get you the biggest linearly independent set. Then you get that the vectors either span a line, 2-dimensional plane, or all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ depending on if there is one, two or three vectors left. In all cases, you should have methods to write these sets in a nice form.